# AppEngine: restrictions on the Datastore Entities `kind` value?

Tags: google-app-engine

When creating Entities with low-level API on AppEngine's Datastore, one must provide the `kind` of the Entity, e.g.

```
Entity newEntity = new Entity("SomeEntityKind", id);
```

Docs are [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity.html), but they do not explain anything about restrictions on `kind`. I also checked AppEngine Python docs, but they do not jave low-level Entities API (and [Key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_from_path) does not list any restrictions on `kind`).

Are there any restrictions on the format of the `kind`? Can it contain whitespace characters? Other special characters? Any length limit?

Does anyone have more info about this?

Comment: Have you tried using a kind with whitespace? What happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, that's underspecified. I'll see about getting that fixed.

Basically, if you stick with names that can derived from class names, you'll be fine. Don't use leading double underscores. I'll check into specific limits later, and will update this.

**Update:** 500 chars max, beginning *and* ending with double underscores is reserved. Don't embed newlines. Unicode might get you in to trouble with parts of the SDKs that don't expect it. Basically, stick with Kind names that can be derived from class names, and you'll be fine.